# Replacing a variable in Rust with same value yields different result

Tags: rust

I could not understand this code. How comes `-a` yields different result from `-7`?

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: i32 = 7; // or any other integer type
    let b = 4;
                
    assert_eq!((-a).rem_euclid(b), 1);
    assert_eq!(-7_i32.rem_euclid(4), -3);
    assert_eq!(-a, -7_i32);
}
```

Playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3147fbbf7aeeeff5510522f9af2d12f2

Comment: It is because in second assertion you negate the result, in first one you negate the operand

Comment: @yolenoyer Because it's a basic question that shows no research and is not useful to others. Playing around with the placement of the parentheses would have shown the difference pretty quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `-7_i32.rem_euclid(4) == -(7_i32.rem_euclid(4))`. The unary negation has [lower precedence](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#expression-precedence) than the method call.